# insert into std::set<struct>

Tags: c++, struct, insert, set

Как заполнить std::set элементами стуктуры struct para { bool flag, int x;} ? Причем para(true,100) и para(false,100) считаются разными элементами и должны успешно инсертиться. При вставке срабатывает operator< . видимо для того чтобы вставить элемент куда нужно. Но его использование делается странным.

```
struct para {
    bool flag;
    int x;
    para(bool i, int x) : flag(i), x(x) {};
    bool operator<(const para& r) const {
        return (r.flag == this->flag || r.x < this->x);                
    }
};
int main()
{
    std::set<para> store1;
    store1.insert(para(false, 10)); //+1 para (нет такой пары в наборе поэтому добавляем её)
    store1.insert(para(true, 10));  //+1 para (нет такой пары в наборе поэтому добавляем её)
    store1.insert(para(true, 11));  //+1 para (нет такой пары в наборе поэтому добавляем её)
    store1.insert(para(true, 10));  //ничего не добавляем в набор (т.к. элемент 
                                    //para(true,10) уже есть в наборе)
}
```

operator< тут работает не очень очевидно. вопрос как я должен оформить
bool operator<(const para& r) const чтобы получить вот такой исход как описан в main (комменты)

Comment: `operator<` тут не работает, если поле `flag` одинаковое у объектов a и b, то a < b и b < a будут давать положительный результат, не обеспечивая требования упорядоченности, как того требует `set`. По-моему `flag` тут должен проверяться после `x`.

Comment: @user7860670 то есть вообще не сделать никак ?

Comment: @user7860670 верно ли я понимаю, что при инсерте происходит сравнение с одним или более элементов. и нужно выяснить ответ куда вставить левее правее или вообще не вставлять. Но как на этот вопрос может ответить operator< ?

Comment: `operator<` должен задавать однозначный порядок между элементами

Comment: @user7860670 , ок. а кто задаёт факт того что вставлять не надо ? ) что такой элемент в наборе уже существует.

Comment: `set` сам проверяет. Гуглите про лексикографический порядок, и реализуйте его в своем `operator<`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да пес с ним с порядком даже.

Comment: Не пес. Чтобы set мог нормально работать, порядок должен быть [нормальным](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/strict_weak_order). У вас при `flag == true` одновременно истино `a < b` и `b > 0` - это явно ненормальный порядок, вот set и ломается.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat
store1.insert(para(false, 10));
    store1.insert(para(true, 10));
    store1.insert(para(true, 11));  вот тут он проверяет так , что инсертиться только первая и последняя пара. а средняя тоже должна.

Comment: *"Чтобы set мог нормально работать, порядок должен быть нормальным"* - вы поняли этот комментарий?

Comment: Факт того что вставлять не надо тоже задается оператором < - с его помощью определяется равенство вставляемого элемента и существующего.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat . да читаю про порядок.

Comment: @user7860670 исход функции оператор<(а,b) либо true , что означает , что a<b , либо ложь которая означает, что a>b || a==b . как вы собрались тут выяснить , что a==b ?

Comment: `!(a<b) && !(b<a)`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  согласен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у `this` и `r` различаются флаги, упорядочиваем их по флагам. Иначе по значениям `x`. Порядок получится таким:

- `(false, *) < (true, *)`
- `(false, x) < (false, y)` если `x < y`
- `(true, x) < (true, y)` если `x < y`

`(false, 1) < (false, 2) < (true, 1) < (true, 2)`

Код:

```
bool operator <(const para& r) const {
    if (!flag && r.flag) {
        return true;
    }
    if (flag && !r.flag) {
        return false;
    }
    return x < r.x;                
}
```

У это порядка есть важное свойство: если `this` и `r` различаются, то или `*this < r` или `r < *this`. Если вы нарушаете это правило, `set` может посчитать различающиеся пары одинаковыми, и отказаться вставлять одну если внутри уже есть другая. Что вы и видели с вашим кодом порядка.

Comment: спасибо большое !

Comment: )) мне вот так понятней : bool operator<(const para& r) const {
        if (flag == r.flag) return x < r.x; else
        if (r.flag) return true; else false;
    }

Comment: Вы хотели сказать:  `if (flag == r.flag) return x < r.x; return r.flag;`. Да, так можно.

Comment: Или даже так: `return (flag == r.flag) ? x < r.x : r.flag;`.

Comment: Разговор не столько про форму кода, сколько про принцип: равенство как отсутствие неравенства.

Answer (score 2):

Я предложил бы  оптимизированный вариант первого ответа. В плане эффективности битовая операция, особенно с одним битом, куда быстрей чем несколько сравнений:

```
bool operator <(const para& r) const {        
    return (flag ^ r.flag) ? r.flag : x < r.x;                
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ

Comment: Можно переписать без смешивания с битовыми операциями: `(flag != r.flag) ? r.flag : x < r.x;`.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, согласен, но, по идеи, та же операция  выполнится

Comment: И я про тоже. Компилятору предоставлена вся информация. Он сам выберет оптимальную последовательность операций - битовых или байтовых.